# How to get button Response/Request URLs in QTP?

Tags: request, response, qtp

How do I get Response/Request URLs (which are shown in `F12 Developer tools - Network` Tab) using QTP 11? Based on these URLs, I need to perform certain action in my application. Is there any alternate solution to get those URLs?

Scenario: Open IE browser and navigate to a URL, Press F12, Go to 'Network' tab. Click on 'Start Capturing' button. Now click on any button or link on the page, you will get a set of URLs in the Developer Tool (F12).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do you need all of the URL requests generated from a button and/or link click? Remember that what you get from the "Network" tab in the developer tools also include URL's for fetching e.g. Javascript and CSS in addition to, for instance a GET request to an external API.

I'll try an provide you with an alternative approach. If what you are really requiring is the URL associated with each interactive element, then you should be able to get that by using the GetROProperty method like so:

```
strURL = Browser("YourBrowser").Page("MainPage").WebButton("aButton").GetROProperty("href")
```

A more generic script for fetching e.g. all the "href" properties for all the links on a page may be found in the following post: [(HP QuickTest) How do I get HTTP status using QuickTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970531/hp-quicktest-how-do-i-get-http-status-using-quicktest).

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:** With regards to your question regarding fetching of the URL's from the IE developer tools; As far as I know there is no way to fetch them from this view by using QTP.

Comment: Yes I need URL request generated from a Button click. And that button doesn't have any value for "Href" property. So when I tried with GetROProperty method it shown nothing. Actually what I need to do in my application is, I have an Audio button, I have to listen to the audio (Audio might be a word/sentence) and need to type that word/sentence in answer box. That word/Sentence is embedded with Button response URL.If I have response URL Then only I can answer correctly...

Comment: By your description it sounds like you are dealing with a CAPTCHA, or is this something else?

Comment: No it's not CAPTCHA, But the functionality would be almost similar.It's an online test to measure student spelling capabilities..

Comment: Ok. Could one of the following workarounds be an option for you?

1.) Keep a fixed sentence in your test environment, or
2.) Ask the developers to embed the sentence value in the web page for the testing environment